# How do I compute this relative holomogy group?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A:=\{z\in S^1: z^n=1\}$, considering $S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$.

Then, how do I compute $H_k(S^1\times S^1, A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$ when $k=1,2$?

Let's consider the long exact sequence of a pair $(S^1\times S^1, A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$:

$...\rightarrow H_k(A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)\rightarrow H_k(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H_k(S^1\times S^1, A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)\rightarrow...$

The problem is when $k=1,2$.

Consider the case $k=2$.

Then, we have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1,A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)\rightarrow H_1(A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$.

Since the outer parts of the sequence are not zero, we have to find explicit forms of the inclusion & boundary maps. Using cellular homology, I know that, a generator of $H_2(S^1\times S^1)$ is $S^1\times S^1$ itself. The problem is, I don't get how the generator of $H_2(S^1\times S^1, A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$ would look like. How do I find it?

Consider the case $k=1$.

We have an exact sequence $H_1(S^1\times S^1)\rightarrow H_1(S^1\times S^1,A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)\rightarrow H_0(A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$.

Since $(S^1\times S^1,A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$ is a good pair, its relative homology is the quotient of these spaces. Let $a,b$ be the most natural generators for $H_1(S^1\times S^1)$. Since $b$ is killed by taking quotient and we are quotienting $A$ too, we get $n+1$ generators, namely $a,b_1,...,b_n$. Since boundary maps take $a,b_1,....b_n$ to zero, boundary map is identically zero.  Since $b$ is killed by taking inclusion and $a$ is preserved by inclusion, we can conclude that $H_1(S^1\times S^1,A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. Is my argument correct?

How do I compute this relative homology group? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Much-improved question!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$H_2(Y)\cong 0$

$H_2(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, generated by $[f_1+f_2+f_3+f_4+f_5]$

$H_1(Y)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, generated by $[e_1]$

$H_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, generated by $[e_1]$  (which equals $[e_2]$, $[e_3]$, $[e_4]$, and $[e_5]$ in this group) and $[e_6+e_7+e_8+e_9+e_{10}]$

$H_0(Y)\cong \mathbb{Z}^5$, generated by $[v_1]$, $[v_2]$, $[v_3]$, $[v_4]$, and $[v_5]$

$H_0(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, generated by $[v_1]$ (which equals $[v_2]$, $[v_3]$, $[v_4]$, and $[v_5]$ in this group)

The map $H_1(Y)\longrightarrow H_1(X)$ has image $\mathbb{Z}[e_1]$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

The map $H_0(Y)\longrightarrow H_0(X)$ has kernel $\mathbb{Z}[v_1-v_2]+\mathbb{Z}[v_2-v_3]+\mathbb{Z}[v_3-v_4]+\mathbb{Z}[v_4-v_5]$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^4$.

Thus $H_1(X,Y)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, such that when you quotient out by it, you get something isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^4$. Therefore $H_1(X,Y)\cong\mathbb{Z}^5$.

The map $H_1(Y)\longrightarrow H_1(X)$ is injective, so the image of the map $H_2(X,Y)\longrightarrow H_1(Y)$ must be the trivial subgroup, so the kernel of the map $H_2(X,Y)\longrightarrow H_1(Y)$ must be all of $H_2(X,Y)$, so the image of the map $H_2(X)\longrightarrow H_2(X,Y)$ must be all of $H_2(X,Y)$, i.e. it is surjective.

Since $H_2(Y)$ is trivial, the map $H_2(X)\longrightarrow H_2(X,Y)$ must be injective.

Therefore $H_2(X,Y)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

$$H_2(Y)\longrightarrow H_2(X)\longrightarrow H_2(X,Y)$$
$$\swarrow$$
$$H_1(Y)\longrightarrow H_1(X)\longrightarrow H_1(X,Y)$$
$$\swarrow$$
$$H_0(Y)\longrightarrow H_0(X)\longrightarrow H_0(X,Y)$$

Comment: Where does $[f_1+...+f_5]$ come from? Why is it the generator of $H_2(X)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What's 
$$
H_1(A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)?
$$
Hint: it's $\Bbb Z$, generated by the $S^1$ factor.

What's 
$$
H_1(S^1\times S^1),
$$
and what are its (most natural) generators?

Hint 2: What's $H_2$ of a 1-complex?

Comment: Well, I know the holomology of the torus and $A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1$. (The latter is just the disjoint union of $n$-points and $S^1$. And I know the most natural generators of the torus. But still I don't get how to compute the relative homology. Could you give me some more details?

Comment: You asked what the inclusion map would look like; it clearly takes the $S^1$ generator for the first group onto the generator of one factor of the second. What does that leave as the quotient?

Comment: Well, that is actually my question.. and I'm also not sure about the boundary map $H_2(S^1\times S^1, A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)\rightarow H_1(A\times \{1\}\cup \{1\} \times S^1)$. Could you give me some more details?

Comment: Nope. This looks like a chameleon question, and I don't do those.

Comment: Umm.. Maybe since I have no experience in homology theory before, I don't get your point. There is no offence and if you felt uncomfortable, I'm sorry. I will edit my post to specify my question.

Comment: A chameleon question is one that keeps changing every time someone answers it. As you might imagine, those who spend time answering find this irritating. State what you know and don't know clearly, and what one thing you need help with, and when you get an answer to that one thing, move on. And ask another question if you find yourself wondering about something else. Sure, that's more work -- but it's more work for *you*, who are the person it's benefitting, which is appropriate.

Comment: I see. I edited my question. Sorry again for being irritating.